# $P$ is in $R^3$ $P_1$ is its projection on the $x_2,x_3$ plane & $P_2$ on $x_1,x_3$, $P_3$ on $x_1,x_2$; prove $A(P)^2=Area(P_1)^2+A(P_2)^2+A(P_3)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Let $P$ be parallelogram in $R^3$ Let $P_1$ be its project on the $x_2,x_3$ plane and $P_2$ on $x_1,x_3$ plane and $P_3$ on $x_1,x_2$; prove $Area(P)^2=Area(P_1)^2+Area(P_2)^2+Area(P_3)^2$**

Well all we need is 2 vectors to form a parallelogram. But the issue is finding its projection onto the 3 different planes. If I could figure that out I would be able to find the areas of each parallelogram from its projected vectors. But I'm unsure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The projection of $\left(x_1, x_2, x_3\right)$ on $x_1x_2$ plan is $(x_1,x_2,0)$ and you can use the fact that the Area of P
$P$ is equal to $$\left\|\vec u \times \vec v\right\|.$$